# Kinect v2 Color Camera Calibration Parameters

Tags: camera-calibration, kinect-v2

I am looking for camera calibration parameters of Kinect V2 color camera. Can someone provide these parameters or any reference?

I know that the camera calibration parameters are lens specific but I am fine with default parameters which Kinect v2 is using.

As always, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each kinect's calibration values are differ by small margins. if you do very precise calculations on them, you will need to calibrate your kinect with a chess board using opencv. Otherwise you can use following values. I calibrated myself.

[All the Kinect v2 calibration parameters](https://github.com/shanilfernando/VRInteraction/tree/master/calibration)